# Android keyboard popupCharacters issues

Tags: android, methods, input, keyboard

I am developing a custom keyboard for android.
I am trying to create a button when pressed smiley faces should popup.
It has come to my understanding that android:popupCharacters is responsible for displaying a popup on the keyboard as well as android:popupKeyboard.
My problem is that for example if i put android:popupCharacters=":) :(" i get a popup with each character on a button by itself.
How is it done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the doc carefully: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#attr_android:popupCharacters

> *android:popupCharacters*
>
> The characters to display **in the popup keyboard**.
>
> [...]
>
> *android:popupKeyboard*
>
> The XML keyboard layout of any popup keyboard.

So popupcharacters means a simpler way to create popupkeyboard. But Unicode comes and saves you from creating XML and using images: http://unicodeemoticons.com/ Try them! (Once I tried a long time ago, well displayed on 2.2 emulator, ZTE Blade and T-Mobile Pulse / Huwaei U8220).

If you don't want this workaround, the other soulution is if you go into the android SDK source, and try to reimplement the whole popup keyboard (or over-implement, if you can) to make it available for you. But anyway, if I was the user, I would be more happy for the unicode or the images, but this is only my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate xml layout for popups in xml directory as the following

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="15%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height"
    >

<Row android:rowEdgeFlags="top">
        <Key android:keyLabel=":-)" android:keyOutputText=":-) "
        <Key android:keyLabel=":-)" android:keyOutputText=":-( "
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

Add as many row and/or key attributes as you like for additional smileys
then use this in your keyboard xml

```
    <Key android:keyOutputText=":-)" android:keylabel=":-)" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup"/>
```

This will create a key ":-)" which will output the character :-) if you press it once, and use the popup xml layout when you long press it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making your own keyboard then check this following source code available which will help you a lot.

[Scandinavian-keyboard](https://code.google.com/p/scandinavian-keyboard/source/checkout)

[Hackers Keyboard](https://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/source/checkout)

[Android Emoji Keyboard](https://github.com/zeuxisoo/android-emoji-keyboard)

Also you want to change theme of your keyboard then check following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528178/how-can-i-implement-special-soft-keyboard/14580859#14580859).It will give you clear idea of how to make preview layout and all. 
And specially if you want to check about smiley then **Android Emoji Keyboard** will be very useful. It uses smiley symbols in keyboard and also in preview too.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Fouad Elia Kada Have you checked Emoji Keyboard code? It helps you or not?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your query correctly and you want to implement something similar to *Watsapp-smiley-button*, then you can make use of [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) in `onClick` of your button and add different smileys to it.