# How can I implement special soft keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I want to make special soft keyboard to use it in my android app like the following

[image]

I worked on the software keyboard sample and I edited the qwerty.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
/* 
**
** Copyright 2008, The Android Open Source Project
**
** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
** you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
** You may obtain a copy of the License at 
**
**     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
**
** Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
** distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
** WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. 
** See the License for the specific language governing permissions and 
** limitations under the License.
*/
-->

<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="6%p"
    >


     <Row   android:keyWidth="18%p">
        <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2"/>
        <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3"/>
        <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4"/>
        <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5"/>
        <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6"/>
        <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7"/>
        <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8"/>
        <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9"/>
        <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
        <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete" 
                android:keyWidth="15%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
                android:isRepeatable="true"/>
    </Row>
    <Row   >
        <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="Q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="W"/>
        <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="E"/>
        <Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="R"/>
        <Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="T"/>
        <Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="Y"/>
        <Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="U"/>
        <Key android:codes="105" android:keyLabel="I"/>
        <Key android:codes="111" android:keyLabel="O"/>
        <Key android:codes="112" android:keyLabel="P" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>

    <Row    >
        <Key android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="A" android:horizontalGap="5%p" 
                android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="115" android:keyLabel="S"/>
        <Key android:codes="100" android:keyLabel="D"/>
        <Key android:codes="102" android:keyLabel="F"/>
        <Key android:codes="103" android:keyLabel="G"/>
        <Key android:codes="104" android:keyLabel="H"/>
        <Key android:codes="106" android:keyLabel="J"/>
        <Key android:codes="107" android:keyLabel="K"/>
        <Key android:codes="108" android:keyLabel="L" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>

    <Row    android:keyHeight="8%p">

        <Key android:codes="122" android:keyLabel="Z"/>
        <Key android:codes="120" android:keyLabel="X"/>
        <Key android:codes="99" android:keyLabel="C"/>
        <Key android:codes="118" android:keyLabel="V"/>
        <Key android:codes="98" android:keyLabel="B"/>
        <Key android:codes="110" android:keyLabel="N"/>
        <Key android:codes="109" android:keyLabel="M"/>
        <Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="."
              />
        <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel="SPACE"
                android:keyWidth="20%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
         <Key android:codes="10" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_return" 
                android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>

    </Row>


</Keyboard>
```

and I get the following

[image]

disregard the first row , how can I make the keyboard button background like the first photo I mean I want to make my keyboard like the first one with all details ? 
How can I add Gmail , Hotmail , ... to the fist row of my keyboard ?
I also want to add a sound when the user click on any key like the default android keyboard 
how can I do that ?

Comment: 1) Google a little 2) read some Android docs and code samples 3) write code 4) fail 5) ask specific question on StackOverflow

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3480756/603233

Comment: I updated my Question , how can I unlock it ?

Comment: I'd like to nominate this for re-opening, but could clarify the question? What do you mean by "how can I make the keyboard button background like the first photo"... otherwise this is a good candidate for re-opening.

Comment: I mean that the first keyboard has a solid background (grey) and the second has gradient background , I read the sample of software keyboard and I didn't find the reason of that and the space button in the first keyboard has darker background , I want to make my keyboard (the second one ) like the first one (which is photo of a keyboard)

Comment: You should have a look at LatinIME from Google: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/.  They customize their keyboard.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create XML like this for keyboard :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.YourKeyboardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    style="@style/keyboard_1_style"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</com.YourKeyboardView>
```

And style is as below:

```
 <style name="keyboard_1_style">
        <item name="android:keyBackground">@drawable/k1_selector</item>
        <item name="android:keyTextColor">#24B2E7</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:keyPreviewLayout">@layout/k1_preview</item>
 </style>
```

In which

```
<item name="android:keyBackground">@drawable/k1_selector</item>
```

is used to set background for key.

```
<item name="android:keyTextColor">#24B2E7</item>
```

is used for text color of key.

```
<item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
```

is used to set background of entire keyboard and

```
<item name="android:keyPreviewLayout">@layout/k1_preview</item>
```

is uesd to set preview of key.

**Preview layout xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/neon_candidate_middle_pressed"/>
```

For spaces between keys use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#attr_android%3ahorizontalGap).

And for `android:background="@drawable/neon_candidate_middle_pressed"` it is background image which you want to show in preview of key.

Comment: @forsubhi Just check my answer and tell me whether this helpful to you or not.

Comment: I try your solution but I need the values of @drawable/k1_selector and @layout/k1_preview

Comment: @forsubhi I have edited..And in selector you have to put 2 images for key background which will work as normal selector.

Comment: @forsubhi Tell me it works for you or not? If yes then please mark it as answer.

Comment: I cannot add  android:background="@drawable/neon_candidate_middle_pressed" and I want to make small spaces between keys see it http://s13.postimage.org/60xxj093r/mykeyboard1.png

Comment: you deserve the bounty , I need also to make small margin at the top of keyboard I mean I put android:horizontalGap="2px"
android:verticalGap="5px"but  I need also gap above the first row of keys

Comment: How can I add Gmail , Hotmail , ... to the fist row of my keyboard ?

Comment: @forsubhi Do you want to directly open Gmail Hotmail from that key or anything else. I am not getting your question.

Comment: I want to add string Hotmail when I click Hotmail

Comment: for example the user write aaa@ and he want to write Hotmail he can directly click on Hotmail key

Comment: @forsubhi Use this : <Key android:keyWidth="13.185714%p" android:keyLabel="Hotmail" android:keyOutputText="Hotmail" android:horizontalGap="1.1%p"/>

Comment: I want to change the font size of them to 8 and use @ too , how can I Do that ?

Comment: How do you get the space key to have a different background? I am trying to get special function keys to have a darker background, I copied a style from Android (<item android:state_single="true" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_keyboard_key_dark_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_single="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_keyboard_key_dark_normal_holo" />

    ) But the marking the keys with state_single=true is not working.

Comment: @Rahil2952 in my custom keyboard with black text and white key background, the text is seem to faded . Plz tell me how I can remove this faded effect from text.