# Add comma in numeric keyboard in xamarin.forms for android

Tags: keyboard, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, samsung-mobile

I need to use both comma and dot in the numeric keyboard in android in xamarin.forms.

I am testing on Samsung S7.

when defining the

`Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric`

in xamarin.forms I can only see dot with the numbers.

I tried custom renderer with:

`protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        InputTypes its = InputTypes.ClassNumber | InputTypes.NumberFlagSigned | InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal;
        Control.SetRawInputType(its);
    }`

but I see the dot with the - sign, no comma

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to use both comma and dot in the numeric keyboard in android in xamarin.forms.

As far as I know, it's not possible to add comma to the default numberic keyboard.

And, the style of software keyboard is not always the same depending on different android system.

For example, I made a demo from your codes and tested it on Google Emulator(Android 6.0) the keyboard shows like below:

[image]

As you can see, there is a comma on the keyboard.

So the only solution I can think of that fullfills your requirement is to create a custom keyboard. For this solution, you can refer to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539198/how-can-i-add-one-extra-row-of-key-to-the-default-android-keyboard).

Answer (score 2):

try phone number as input type. it is the only numeric keyboard type out of the box that offers point and comma.

Comment: there is no difference on samsung devices. phone will not work as well

Comment: Keyboard="Telephone" looks a bit weird if you expect the user to enter a numeric value. Telephone keyboard not only shows keypad numbers 0-9 but also the oldschool alphabetic characters on each keypad.... this could be very confusing if the user is expected to enter e.g. an amount