# How to create a custom keyboard that looks like the standard one

Tags: java, android, eclipse, keyboard, ime

I am experimenting with custom ime on android. The sample SoftKeyboard app seems to show everything I need except how to make the keyboard look like the standard one (colors, hover effects, sizes etc.). 
It seems like reusing resources from the standard keyboard sources could work, but I receive errors when trying to compile them like:

**error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr android:layout_alignParentStart'.**

Commenting these errors produce lots of other XML errors, like:

**error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'additionalMoreKeys' in package 'com.android.inputmethod.latin' key_f1.xml**

Is there some semi automatic a way to fix these errors and make them compile?

I have got the sources from here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/android-4.4.2_r2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on your purpose.
If you want to create keyboard specifically to any activity then follow below tutorial.

http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html

Or if you want to create keyboard that will replace default keyboard in all applications then following answer will be helpful to you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806087/android-facebook-emoji-keyboard/14826813

As you said you want to change layout of keyboard then read [this](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm).

Comment: I need to replace the default keyboard and I already have found a number of examples and other information in this regard. The problem I am still having is how to make my keyboard look as similar to the standard one as possible.

Comment: check this answer hope that helps you somewhat.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528178/how-can-i-implement-special-soft-keyboard/14580859

Comment: Thanks, this should be enough to push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could browse the android source code: [android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java?av=f) and 
[android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.java?av=f) and look for the specific behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard found in android is open source, along with most of the other packages found in the OS. You can see the code here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/android-4.4.2_r2

Comment: Yea, those sources might help. Maybe I can reuse the stuff from the "java/res" folder.